# IntelliJ Idea IDE using port 1099

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty, rmi

I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition IDE and I'm trying to run a Maven WebApp with       Jetty by command line. I'm on a RedHat box

I run this command:

```
mvn clean install -P deployJetty -Djetty.port=8083
```

And I get this error:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

The funny thing is that when I close IntelliJ Idea, the 1099 port is released.
I can't find the reason why and how Idea is using this port.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Note: As a workaround, I'm closing Idea, running Jetty and then opening Idea (and I guess forcing it to pick another port)

Comment: So obviously IntelliJ is using port 1099, probably for an RMI Registry of its own.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am sure IntelliJ Idea does not use 1099 port internally. I have used this PORT for Tomcat. I would suggest checking if any of idea plugins that you have installed are running on this port. Most of the operating systems can give you the application name that is running on that port.

Eg: `lsof -w -n -i tcp:8080` would give me the application running on **8080** on my linux machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The process using port 1099 is 'java' (jdk through IntelliJ). But you had the solution. The issue was in FindBugs plugin. Uninstalling it solved the problem. Thank you @Sachi!

Comment: It was findbugs for me too. I really don't know why, that plugin was never a problem.. but after I updated tomcat it.. it was sitting on the port

Answer (score 11):

Go to terminal and kill the session

```
ps -aef | grep 1099
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 5):

on windows :

step 1] find the process : netstat -ano  or netstat -aon |find /i "listening" |find "Port no"

step 2] kill the process : Taskkill /F /IM (Process id obtained from above step)

Please see example below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have localhost defined in your `/etc/hosts` file, and that it's defined only once

```
localhost         127.0.0.1
```

it was leaving the maven process in intelliJ hanging which caused the `port 1099 already in use` error even after changing the jmx port to something different.

Comment: Helped on similar issue (port 1100)

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac a process called "fsnotifier" is using port 1099. A google on this indicates that it's an IntelliJ file system watcher. Solved by using a different port for JMX.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got disconnected from the JBoss instance that I had started in IDEA, and the server continued to run, thus using the 1099 port for JMX.

You can either kill the server process using that port (it'll be a java process using a lot of memory) or create a remote debug configuration that you can use in case you don't want to restart the server. Use the same debug ports for the local and remote debug configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is easy to tackle with **Terminal**.
Open the Terminal and type following.

```
fuser 1099/tcp
```

If a process uses above port, it should return something output like this.

```
1099/tcp:            2222
```

The last column value (2222) is referred to the Process ID (**PID**).

Just **KILL** it as follows.

```
kill -9 2222
```

Now you can start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

On windows command line :

**1.** find which process uses port 1099

**`netstat -ano -p tcp |find "1099"`**

[image]

**2.** Process with PID 2112 is listening on port 1099. Now we can query task list to find the process.

**`tasklist |find "2112"`**

[image]

Also You can check the windows task manager.
[image]

**3.** Kill the process from task manager, by right click on the item and selecting *End task* or via command line :

**`taskkill /F /PID 2112`**